# Delphi - How to monitor the network

Tags: delphi, network-programming, delphi-2010

Can someone give me some indications about how to log the web pages accessed(using any web browser)? Should I make a global proxy.... hook the network....? All that I need to log is the page address, not the info contained in it.

I am using Delphi.

Thank you

I am looking, if is possible, for a solution without using Winpcap

Edit:
I just found [Internet Packet Monitoring Components](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp) by Magenta Systems.

Comment: If the monitoring components have resolved your question, then mention them as an *answer* to this question; don't edit the *question* to add an answer. Even though you asked the question, you're allowed to answer it, too. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer: [Internet Packet Monitoring Components(free)](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magmonsock.asp) by Magenta Systems